# Delay App Progression Until Firebase Data Retrieval Is Finished

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my app, I store data on the Firebase database (**Firestore AND Storage**) in the form of "Files" (what the user sees). When the user goes to their "Files" tab and selects a certain file (example: "Smith vs Wesson"), the app downloads data on the server (from BOTH **Firestore** and **Storage**) related to that file. Here's my problem: the app moves forward before the data has even finished returning and processing (sorted/stored into variables). I don't want the app to progress and take the user to the next screen until this is totally complete. The next three screens show the data retrieved from the server, so if it's moving forward before the data has even retrieved and sorted... well... you see the problem with that.

I tried using something like DispatchQueque.main.asyncAfter to add a three second delay, but the problem with this is that if the user's internet connection is poor, it may take longer than three seconds to retrieve the data. Likewise, if their internet connection is booming, it may take only a second to retrieve the data, but they're still stuck waiting on an unnecessary three-second delay. I only want the delay to last as long as it takes for the retrieval/sorting/storing function to complete its tasks... no matter how short or long.

I'm still learning and am mostly self-taught, so forgive my ignorance. From what I understand from the reading I've been doing, tasks are based off of "threads." The main thread is what the user sees, while there are threads that tasks can be done in the background to keep the user from experiencing longer wait times, etc (such as data retrieval from a server). I know typically you don't want to do tasks on the main thread, but in this case where I don't want the user to be able to progress, I need to find a way to pause the main thread until the other thread has completed the data retrieval and sorting/storing process.

I stumbled across something called "CountDownLatch." I read about it and kind of understand the concept of it... but not the code at all, to be honest. I don't know if CountDownLatch is the correct method to use here or not, but if it is, could someone please show me how I could use either CountDownLatch, or some other delay, to pause the progression of the app until the data is retrieved, sorted, and stored into the variables?

My data retrieval/sorting/storing function is called "getAndAppendClaimData." I handle all of those steps in this function, and it works perfectly. Like I said, I just need to provide some delay until it's finished, so that the code underneath this function isn't executed thereby segueing to the next screen.

So something kinda like this:

```
while getAndAppendClaimData is still processing {
   showLoadingAnimation
}

once getAndAppendClaimData has finished **ALL** of its tasks {
   performSegue to next screen
}
```

NOTE: I **DON'T** use listeners in my app because I don't need to update the user's screen in realtime... like with a messaging app or something. I just use the ***.getDocuments*** and ***documents.forEach*** functionalities for my data retrieval.

Please explain your answers or provide links to content explanations. You remember how it was when you were still learning..

Also, before some of you call this post a duplicate.. the other threads are outdated and most of them deal with apps that have listeners for realtime updates – which is different from my circumstance. Another thing, I'm doing a lot of research and learning... so please don't drop the whole "go do your research" bomb. Sometimes you need help tailoring things to your specific situation.

Thanks, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: There are many possible ways to solve this, but it's possible that someone would provide a solution that doesn't really relate to your situation because you may have chosen a different architecture (ie UIKit vs SwiftUI). Can you show us some code?

Comment: I use view controllers. The FilesViewController has a table view in it that displays the Firebase "documents" using a querySnapshot. When the user selects the specific document, it simply takes the specifics out of that document using a second query and snapshot.documents.forEach. Gets the value of the different keys and stores them in variable. A typical "read" from Firestore. If there's an image in the document, then it will get the image from Storage as well.

Comment: Would a DispatchGroup probably be the best general way? @jnpdx

Comment: This is the issue *I don't want the app to progress and take the user to the next screen until this is totally complete*. That's easy to accomplish when you take into account the asynchronous nature of Firebase. We can probably help but seeing your code will be a requirement. If you look at the example in your question, that's the issue. The `once getAndAppendClaimData...` code will run BEFORE the code above completes so you have to code asynchronously. Update your question and see this [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also note that [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#monitor_download_progress) has a pretty cool progress function so as a file is downloading, you can present a 'download bar' or other indicator to the user so they know the app is functioning and waiting for the download to complete. There's actually an event that fires `FIRStorageTaskStatusSuccess` when the download is complete that can be used to allow the user to progress to the next step.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after more research, I found that one way to keep your app from progressing while server data is downloading and sorting is with **DispatchGroup**.

First of all, create a DispatchGroup variable:

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
```

Then you can ***"enter"*** the group at the beginning of the call/function and ***"leave"*** the group at the end, once everything has finished processing (such as in ***completion*** in a Firebase call). If you're utilizing a loop to sort your data, then make sure to ***enter*** dispatchGroup

```
dispatchGroup.enter()
```

every time you enter the loop and ***leave*** dispatchGroup

```
dispatchGroup.leave()
```

at the end of each loop iteration. Once you're finished entering and leaving dispatchGroup for good, then call:

```
dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
   // Here write whatever you want to do after it's finished retrieving and processing the data...
   // Such as performing a segue
}
```

You would call this .notify **outside** of your loop, of course.

In my situation, I had a two loops: one to gather/store server data and one to sort it. I didn't want it to start trying to sort until it had finished gathering/sorting, so I executed the second loop inside ***dispatchGroup.notify***, then performed my segue after the second loop finished.

Watch these three tutorials, they helped me out big time!

[DispatchQueues](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hmu0v_25pgc)

[DispatchGroups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4zsNgBhDs0M)

[Semaphore vs DispatchGroup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rJN_ECd1XM)

Comment: While dispatch groups are cool - they can be tricky especially if you're embedding asynchronous code inside them; the results can be unpredictable as one day, suddenly for no reason, everything is running out of order and randomly crashing in different places. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: Okay thanks for letting me know. I'll pay attention to it and look for a different solution in the future, if necessary.